# Declaring custom 'clean' task when using the standard Gradle lifecycle plugins is not allowed

Tags: android-studio, gradle, kotlin

I am building a kotlin android project. When i configure kotlin in android studio, i get this error in the gradle file.

```
Declaring custom 'clean' task when using the standard Gradle lifecycle plugins is not allowed
```

This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933459/declaring-custom-clean-task-when-using-the-standard-gradle-lifecycle-plugins-i) but no help still. What might be the issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933459/declaring-custom-clean-task-when-using-the-standard-gradle-lifecycle-plugins-i and the author knows this.

Comment: I stated that in my question.

Comment: I answered the question there.

Comment: That you stated it in your question doesn't make it more correct. You cannot go into a bank and say "I shouldn't rob you, but give me all your money". You would still be arrested. ;-)

Comment: i get you buddy, now provide me with the exact link of your answer

Comment: You should at least add the relevant parts of your Gradle files.

Comment: @NyagakaEnock The link is not different to yours, just click your own link ;-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46271978/6749161