# Configuring Kotlin in New Android Studio Project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

I have installed kotlin plugin and created a new project in studio. I have been to Tools > Kotlin > Configure Kotlin in Project and followed all the steps but my gradle build does not work.

I am getting this error:

```
Error:(24, 0) Declaring custom 'clean' task when using the standard Gradle lifecycle plugins is not allowed.
```

Open File

Can someone point out to me what is wrong or show me the proper way to setup android studio for kotlin. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring custom 'clean' task when using the standard Gradle lifecycle plugins is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933459/declaring-custom-clean-task-when-using-the-standard-gradle-lifecycle-plugins-i)

Comment: Am trying to create new kotlin project in studio, pls point out what the error is.

Comment: Are you done with this steps:  Preferences > Plugins > Browse Repositories and search for “Kotlin” then, click on “Install”

Comment: @shweta, yes I have done those steps. Tell me how to configure AS for kotlin

Comment: Never mind, I have fixed it. Issue is closed. Thanks everyone.

Comment: How is it solved?