# When loading a project apply script build.gradle error occur

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to load a project then at first it has couple of problems with the version of build:gradle then i tried fixing it by changing the version to 3.2.1 cause I had those problems before and most of the time they were solved but this time there was an error inside and I really dont know what to do. It says "Declaring custom 'clean' task when using the standard Gradle lifecycle plugins is not allowed.
Open File"

AndroidLogin:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google() // here
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google() // and here
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
}
```

App\build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.androidtutorialpoint.androidlogin"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'

}
```

I also read about changing the compile to AndroidTestCompile but it didnt also work

Comment: remove taskClean part

Comment: can you please tell me which error you face after project build?

Comment: Declaring custom 'clean' task when using the standard Gradle lifecycle plugins is not allowed.
Open File

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring custom 'clean' task when using the standard Gradle lifecycle plugins is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933459/declaring-custom-clean-task-when-using-the-standard-gradle-lifecycle-plugins-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove this clean task and **clean/build** app again.

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Update**

Replace `compile` with `implementation` or `api`, Check [Dependency configurations](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies?utm_source=android-studio#dependency_configurations)

```
dependencies {
api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
}
```

Comment: I tried and couple of warning pop up Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
and 2 more instead of 'compile' it's 'testcompile' and 'testApi'

Comment: Yes, Replace each `compile` with `implementation`.